# Center a div with horizontal width greater than window width

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

I have a list that spreads outward in a hierarchical tree structure on the page. I need to center the list on page load allowing the user to scroll right and left.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tree">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So let's say the window size or inner width of the body is 1000px. And let's say .tree is 2000px. I need to load the page so that .tree is -500px to the left with the horizontal scroll bar centered so that the user can move left and right to see all 2000px of .tree.

My unsuccessful attempt

```
    $innerWidth = $('body').innerWidth();
    $treeWidth = $(".tree ul:first").width();
    $(".tree").css("width", $treeWidth);
    if ($treeWidth > $innerWidth) {
        $treeDiff = ($treeWidth - $innerWidth) / 2;
        $(".container").css({"min-width" : $treeWidth, "margin-left" : -$treeDiff, "width" : $treeWidth});
    } else {
        $(".container").css({"min-width" : $treeWidth, "width" : $innerWidth});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the following in **the event that causes the tree to spread**:

```
var newWidthDec = parseFloat($('.tree').css('width').replace('px',''));
var newWidth = Math.ceil(newWidthFloat);

window.scrollTo((newWidth/2),0);
```

**Note the left end of the scrollbar will be close to center-page.**